# Combine multiple files into one including the file name

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cat

I have been looking around trying to combine multiple text files into including the name of the file.

My current file content is:

```
1111,2222,3333,4444
```

What I'm after is:

```
File1,1111,2222,3333,4444
File1,1111,2222,3333,4445
File1,1111,2222,3333,4446
File1,1111,2222,3333,4447
File2,1111,2222,3333,114444
File2,1111,2222,3333,114445
File2,1111,2222,3333,114446
```

I found multiple example how to combine them all but nothing to combine them including the file name.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they put in order to solve their own problems. So please do add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Very unclear what you want to do. Sorry.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, everything I tried with cat/awk etc... didn't work how I wish to.

Comment: @stephanmg, I'm trying to combine all the files in one, while the new file will also have a column with the file name, as per above example.

Comment: @Svan, no worries no body going to say anything if your attempt is wrong or right people are supportive here only rule is we all here to learn, which applies to all, so please always do add your efforts in your question and trust me you will get great Guidance on this great site SO, cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following. Considering that your Input_file names extensions are `.csv`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print FILENAME,$0}' *.csv > output_file
```

After seeing OP's comments if file extensions are `.txt` then try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print FILENAME,$0}' *.txt > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your files have a `.txt` extension and contain only one line as in the example, you can use the following code:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo "$f,$(cat "$f")"; done > output.log
```

where `output.log` is the output file.

Comment: @stephanmg Looks like necessary use of cat to me.

Comment: Well, this solution will only work for files with a single line of content. If a file has more then 1 line, it will only prepend the filename to the first line of input....

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt |
xargs -n1 -d $'\n' bash -c 'xargs -n1 -d $'\''\n'\'' printf "%s,%s\n" "$1" <"$1"' --
```

1. First output a newline separated list of files.
2. Then for each file `xargs` execute `sh`

   3. Inside sh execute `xargs` for each line of file

      4. and it executes `printf "%s,%s\n" <filename>` for each line of input

Tested in [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FumblingIllfatedPlan).

Comment: Thank you, the result is: file1..txt: : No such file or directory

Comment: Och, okej, let's see. Edited the answer. After changing `sh` to `bash`, it works on external site on `repl`. So please check if you copied and/or used the code exactly as intended or post your code to check.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `grep "" *.txt -I > $filename`.